# Practice Wordpress without having a website

Tags: wordpress, web, content-management-system

I am starting with web development CMS (Wordpress) and I would like to practice with it without needing to have a website myself.

Is there any kind of Wordpress simulator or something so I dont need to buy a domain, pay a hosting... to practice with it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. However, questions asking for recommendations of products or hosting are off-topic there as well as here.

Comment: Well, I am not asking for hosting or something like that, just asking if there was any way to make a simulated web in my local machine without having to have it live on the internet. Refering to Webmasters, yeah, is true I should have asked there, I didnt know that web existed. My bad, I am new in programming and just know the basics, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can find a free hosting website.

Or you can deploy a local version of WordPress. You can do that by downloading Wamp (for Windows) or Lamp (for Linux).
You can check this guide if you want to go further: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-your-windows-computer-using-wamp/